# C# event bubbling

Tags: c#, winforms, events, backgroundworker

I'm having a little trouble to achieve the following:

Form1 has two buttons "Validate" and "Cancel", also has a BackgroundWorker.
Class1 has a heavy processing method.

Clicking "Validate" calls the DoWork which heavy work is a method of Class1. I've managed to "listen" for progress changes events in my DoWork, that arise from Class1 method.

Now, I'm trying to cancel the heavy dutty (inside the method) when the button Cancel is clicked.

```
private void buttonCancelValidation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 obj = new Class1();
        obj.ProgressChanged += (s, pe) => backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(pe.ProgressPercentage);

        //---> Here a i'm trying to "tell" class1 that if the "Cancel" button was clicked then I want to abort ASAP the HeavyMethod operation.

        obj.HeavyMethod();

        //followed by the cancel of BackgroundWorker DoWork
        if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending  
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Charles how to tell from FORM1 to another class object method that cancel was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing how the HeavyMethod works, the only way you can do this is to have the thread wait until the HeavyMethod completes, or provide a way to interupt the HeavyMethod from within the obj class.

You could have Class1 accept a reference to the backgroundWorker object so that the HeavyMethod could check the value of the CancellationPending flag and break in that method. This would only work if your HeavyMethod has a loop or a set of smaller tasks in which you can check this flag between the tasks in order to break or return from the method early.

You could accomplish this like so

```
public class Class1
{
   private BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker = null;
   public Class1(BackgroundWorkerThread worker)
   {
     _backgroundWorker = worker;
     // rest of constructor
   }

   public void HeavyWorker()
   {
      // Heavy work

      // Have we been cancelled.
      if (_backgroundWorker != null && _backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
      {
         // perform clean up and return
      }

       // Perform more heavy work.
   }
} 

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(...)
{
   Class1 obj = new Class1(backgroundWorker);

   obj.HeavyMethod();
}
```

Comment: I'm simply reading a file in HeavyMethod, in a loop so i can abort it in that loop. 
If it was your choice would you go with your 1st solution or the 2nd one?
I think i read somewhere that it wasn't a good idea to pass BGW to another class object.

Comment: I don't recall reading anything about it being an issue with passing a BGW to another class object as long as that object is only around during the execution of the backgroundWorker. Because once the thread is done working, the object with the reference to the worker should be disposed of. This issue is when you start getting references to stale background workers.  And I would just put the check as seen above within the loop, and don't forget to close the file if you get canceled.

Comment: I will try to find that to ensure I'm not messing concepts.
So that's perfect, will use this solution, that already used in another project, but indeed i was a little bit unsure of this approach!

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Your `HeavyMethod()` code has to be able to access some, let's say boolean, variable which should indicate if it need to return immediately. How often you will check for that variable value inside `HeavyMethod()` code will vary the latency between the moment user clicked Cancel button and action actually stopped.

```
bool cancelValidationRequest = false; 
private void buttonCancelValidation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancelValidationRequest = true; // this will cause HeavyMethod return asap
        backgroundWorker.CancelAsync(); // this makes requet to thread to stop, but it still in HeavyMethod...
    }
```

and inside `HeavyMethod()`

```
private void HeavyMethod() 
{   

    //execute heavy code 
    if(cancelValidationRequest ) return; 

   // continue execute heavy code 
    if(cancelValidationRequest ) return; 

   ..... 
   ....
}
```

Something like this, just to give an idea.

**EDIT**

As Wizetux pointed out, you have to pay attention on the fact that bolean value (in this specific case) is manipulated by different threads.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As he said, you need to check for termination requests periodically : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Due to the fact that you will be setting and getting the value of the bool from two different threads, you will have to worry about the thread safety of this task so that you don't end up in a race condition. I believe the backgroundWorker object does this internally.

Comment: @Tigran lol that easy... eheheh. Obj is instantied in DoWork, so in ButttonCancelValidation is not known. Is it ok to make the cancelValidationRequest a static property in Class1? Made a quick teste and it is Ok.

Comment: @Libas: I would suggest use member variable. Check this out: http://geekswithblogs.net/chrishan/archive/2005/11/04/59102.aspx

Comment: @Tigran to do that, obj should be a field in Form1, don't like this too much. Thanks for pointing that issue!
Think I will go 2nd Wizetux solution